# How can I get DejaDup to ONLY backup to UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, backup, cloud, deja-dup

How can I get DejaDup to ONLY backup to UbuntuOne?  I installed 11.10 on a small partition two weeks ago, setup for daily backups and forgot about it. Next thing I know the disk was filled up and I didn't realize why.

Syncing can be nice but some things I want to push off my local disk space onto the cloud storage. Like low-priority background backups.  I also can't seem to find Duplicity detailed settings like extensions to ignore, file size limit cutoff etc, though that's a separate question.

Comment: Can you please give us a screen shot of your dejadup preferences?

Comment: Hello!  I'm the maintainer of Deja Dup.  This sounds like a bug.  If you're up for it, please file a bug and I can walk you through getting some information and possible workarounds.  https://launchpad.net/deja-dup/+filebug

Comment: Thanks guys for great responsiveness(not to mention software)! My new findings below lead me to believe dejadup was working fine all along....I probably confused it as part of the same thing as `ubuntuone-control-panel` early on--which seems like what caused the re-downloads back to local

Answer (score 3):

In Deja Dup, you should be able to set your Backup Location to Ubuntu One, and then it'll only back up to there. Is that not working for you?

[image: backup location selector]

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot of `deja-dup-preferences`. No not working for me--yes it is syncing to Ubuntu One as selected(don't see another option there that would, directly; custom or webdav maybe?), but it is also filling up my local ~/**deja-dup/desktop** folder, so I've had to disable Deja Dup for now.

Answer (score 0):

When I run `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` 
under the **Cloud Folders** tab, the first folder called  **Ubuntu One** is *Always in sync* and cannot be disabled. No problemo.

The second folder is **deja-dup/desktop** from above, and **Sync Locally?**  was previously enabled.
That might have been it.  Disabling and checking.